# Invoke SAP Webmethods in ASP.NET app?

Tags: asp.net

Can any body help me on calling a SAP Webmethod using ASP.NET application.

Thanks,
-Narendra

Comment: How are these exposed? Is there a WSDL url/file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are standard web services, see the following MSDN articles:

- [How to: Add and Remove Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx)
- [How to: Call a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h0yh8f9.aspx)

There is quite a lot of documentation about [web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx) on MSDN.